# Pandas Split Mixed Type And Get First Element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, datetime-format

Given the following data frame, which came from importing a messy Excel spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c'],
        'dates':['2015-08-31 00:00:00','2015-08-24 00:00:00','8/3/2015, 1/4/16']})

try:
    df['dates']=df['dates'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
except:
    pass
df

    A   dates
0   a   2015-08-31 00:00:00
1   b   2015-08-24 00:00:00
2   c   8/3/2015, 1/4/16
```

I want to split where more than one date exists and take only the first one like this:

```
    A   dates
0   a   2015-08-31 00:00:00
1   b   2015-08-24 00:00:00
2   c   8/3/2015
```

I'm hoping it will convert the result to the same format like this:

```
    A   dates
0   a   2015-08-31 00:00:00
1   b   2015-08-24 00:00:00
2   c   2015-08-03 00:00:00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `to_datetime()` in conjunction with `.str.split()`:

```
In [215]: pd.to_datetime(df.dates.str.split(',\s*').str[0])
Out[215]:
0   2015-08-31
1   2015-08-24
2   2015-08-03
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

or

```
In [216]: df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dates.str.split(',\s*').str[0])

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
   A      dates
0  a 2015-08-31
1  b 2015-08-24
2  c 2015-08-03
```

dtypes:

```
In [219]: df.dtypes
Out[219]:
A                object
dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```